# Optimize time critical t-sql statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and it is very slow, and i am not sure what i can improve.
The sql server table EntityValue only contains 1'800 rows.

here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetReportLabelValues](
    @UnitIds UniqueIdentifierTableType readonly, 
    @LabelIds UniqueIdentifierTableType readonly)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT LabelValue.EntityId AS [LabelId], LabelValue.UnitId AS [UnitId], LabelValue.Value AS [Value]
    FROM EntityValue, LabelValue
    WHERE 
        EntityValue.IsDeleted = 0 AND
        EntityValue.UnitId = LabelValue.UnitId AND
        EntityValue.EntityId = LabelValue.EntityId AND
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @UnitIds WHERE EntityValue.UnitId = [@UnitIds].Id) AND
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @LabelIds WHERE EntityValue.EntityId = [@LabelIds].Id)

END;
```

What is wrong with this statement? Or do i need to set some additional indices?
Thank you for your help in advance :)
best
laurin

Edit:

Here is the excution plan:

```
DECLARE @unitIds AS UniqueIdentifierTableType;
INSERT INTO @unitIds ([Id]) VALUES ('63ABF15E-B8B0-4240-9B90-08F324D5179E') 1   1   0   NULL    NULL    1   NULL    1   NULL    NULL    NULL    0.01000216  NULL    NULL    INSERT  0   NULL
  |--Table Insert(OBJECT:(@unitIds), SET:([Id] = [Expr1004]), DEFINE:([Expr1004]={guid'63ABF15E-B8B0-4240-9B90-08F324D5179E'})) 1   2   1   Table Insert    Insert  OBJECT:(@unitIds), SET:([Id] = [Expr1004]), DEFINE:([Expr1004]={guid'63ABF15E-B8B0-4240-9B90-08F324D5179E'})    [Expr1004]={guid'63ABF15E-B8B0-4240-9B90-08F324D5179E'} 1   0.01    1E-06   9   0.01000216  NULL    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1

DECLARE @labelIds AS UniqueIdentifierTableType;
INSERT INTO @labelIds ([Id]) VALUES ('4E75B50C-E647-42E7-A87F-2D23D8B63D17')    2   3   0   NULL    NULL    2   NULL    1   NULL    NULL    NULL    0.01000216  NULL    NULL    INSERT  0   NULL
  |--Table Insert(OBJECT:(@labelIds), SET:([Id] = [Expr1004]), DEFINE:([Expr1004]={guid'4E75B50C-E647-42E7-A87F-2D23D8B63D17'}))    2   4   3   Table Insert    Insert  OBJECT:(@labelIds), SET:([Id] = [Expr1004]), DEFINE:([Expr1004]={guid'4E75B50C-E647-42E7-A87F-2D23D8B63D17'})   [Expr1004]={guid'4E75B50C-E647-42E7-A87F-2D23D8B63D17'} 1   0.01    1E-06   9   0.01000216  NULL    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1

exec dbo.GetReportLabelValues @unitIds, @labelIds   3   5   0   NULL    NULL    3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    EXECUTE PROC    0   NULL

CREATE PROCEDURE GetReportLabelValues(
    @UnitIds UniqueIdentifierTableType readonly, 
    @LabelIds UniqueIdentifierTableType readonly)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT LabelValue.EntityId AS [LabelId], LabelValue.UnitId AS [UnitId], LabelValue.Value AS [Value]
    FROM EntityValue, LabelValue
    WHERE 
        EntityValue.IsDeleted = 0 AND
        EntityValue.UnitId = LabelValue.UnitId AND
        EntityValue.EntityId = LabelValue.EntityId AND
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @UnitIds WHERE EntityValue.UnitId = [@UnitIds].Id) AND
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @LabelIds WHERE EntityValue.EntityId = [@LabelIds].Id)    4   6   5   NULL    NULL    5   NULL    1.062501    NULL    NULL    NULL    0.02785614  NULL    NULL    SELECT  0   NULL
       |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[UnitId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[EntityId]) DEFINE:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[Value]=ANY([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[Value])))   4   8   6   Stream Aggregate    Aggregate   GROUP BY:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[UnitId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[EntityId])   [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[Value]=ANY([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[Value])  1.062501    0   1.062501E-06    343 0.02785614  [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[UnitId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[EntityId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[Value]  NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
            |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[UnitId], [Id]))  4   9   8   Nested Loops    Inner Join  OUTER REFERENCES:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[UnitId], [Id])   NULL    1.062501    0   4.441255E-06    375 0.02785508  [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[UnitId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[EntityId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[UnitId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[EntityId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[Value]    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
                 |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[EntityId]=[Id]))   4   10  9   Nested Loops    Inner Join  WHERE:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[EntityId]=[Id]) NULL    1.062501    0   0.0001594845    55  0.02455766  [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[UnitId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[EntityId], [Id]  NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
                 |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Id]))  4   12  10  Nested Loops    Inner Join  OUTER REFERENCES:([Id]) NULL    38.15419    0   0.0001594845    39  0.01814615  [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[UnitId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[EntityId]    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
                 |    |    |--Sort(DISTINCT ORDER BY:([Id] ASC))    4   13  12  Sort    Distinct Sort   DISTINCT ORDER BY:([Id] ASC)    NULL    1   0.01126126  0.000100023 23  0.01464438  [Id]    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
                 |    |    |    |--Table Scan(OBJECT:(@UnitIds))    4   14  13  Table Scan  Table Scan  OBJECT:(@UnitIds)   [Id]    1   0.003125    0.0001581   23  0.0032831   [Id]    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
                 |    |    |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[PK_EntityValue]), SEEK:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[UnitId]=[Id]),  WHERE:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[IsDeleted]=(0)) ORDERED FORWARD)   4   15  12  Clustered Index Seek    Clustered Index Seek    OBJECT:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[PK_EntityValue]), SEEK:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[UnitId]=[Id]),  WHERE:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[IsDeleted]=(0)) ORDERED FORWARD   [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[UnitId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[EntityId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[IsDeleted]   38.15419    0.003125    0.0001989696    40  0.00332397  [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[UnitId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[EntityId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[IsDeleted]   NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
                 |    |--Table Scan(OBJECT:(@LabelIds)) 4   17  10  Table Scan  Table Scan  OBJECT:(@LabelIds)  [Id]    1   0.0032035   7.96E-05    31  0.006240574 [Id]    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   38.15419
                 |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[PK_LabelValue]), SEEK:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[UnitId]=[ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[UnitId] AND [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[EntityId]=[Id]) ORDERED FORWARD)   4   19  9   Clustered Index Seek    Clustered Index Seek    OBJECT:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[PK_LabelValue]), SEEK:([ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[UnitId]=[ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[EntityValue].[UnitId] AND [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[EntityId]=[Id]) ORDERED FORWARD [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[UnitId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[EntityId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[Value]  1   0.003125    0.0001581   343 0.003292982 [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[UnitId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[EntityId], [ABB_MDB2_Test].[dbo].[LabelValue].[Value]  NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1.062501
```

Comment: Instead of the two correlated subqueries, you can do a join. That's a start. As for "additional indices" - what are the current ones? Are they being used? What does the query plan look like?

Comment: What does your execution plan look like?

Comment: What is this `UniqueIdentifierTableType`?

Comment: @Kaf - Looks like a [table valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

Comment: Hmm. first time I saw that. Thanks @Oded.

Comment: Hey guys, the UniqueIdentifierTableType is only a TVP that contains just an Id (of type unique identifier).

Comment: @Joe: How do i show the execution plan for a stored procedure?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794411/how-can-i-display-the-execution-plan-for-a-stored-procedure

Comment: @Oded: There are no indices except the the primary key which is a combined one for EntityValue (UnitId and EntityId)

Comment: Is one of these also the table primary key?

Comment: @Oded: Sorry i am not sure if i understand you right: yes it is a combined primary key: UnitId & EntityId

Comment: Hm i can not attach the exceution plan i will update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I converted the sub-queries to joins.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetReportLabelValues]
(
    @UnitIds UniqueIdentifierTableType readonly, 
    @LabelIds UniqueIdentifierTableType readonly
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT LabelValue.EntityId AS [LabelId], 
           LabelValue.UnitId AS [UnitId], 
           LabelValue.Value AS [Value]
    FROM EntityValue
    JOIN LabelValue ON EntityValue.UnitId = LabelValue.UnitId AND 
                    EntityValue.EntityId = LabelValue.EntityId
    JOIN @UnitID ON EntityValue.UnitId = [@UnitIds].Id
    JOIN @LabelIds ON EntityValue.EntityId = [@LabelIds].Id
    WHERE EntityValue.IsDeleted = 0 
END;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks :)
Btw: The improvement is immense sql profiler says from 21'000 MS to 940ms.

Comment: @LaurinSt - As expected, it went from `O(X * 2Y)` to `O(X + 2Y)`