# Need tips to optimize SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my stored procedure, it's taking some time to execute even though running with local database.

Please suggest changes in order to improve the performance

```
BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @COUNTRY_CD INT
        SET @COUNTRY_CD =(SELECT COUNTRY_CD FROM COUNTRY WHERE COUNTRY_DESC = LTRIM(RTRIM(@COUNTRY_DESC)))
        DECLARE @COMPANNY_CD INT
        SET @COMPANNY_CD =(SELECT COMPANY_CD FROM COMPANY WHERE COMPANY_DESC = LTRIM(RTRIM(@COMPANY_DESC)))
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DELETE FROM PACK 
        WHERE   COUNTRY_CD = @COUNTRY_CD 
                AND COMPANY_CD = @COMPANNY_CD
                AND PACK_DESC = LTRIM(RTRIM(@PACK_DESC))
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF(@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), 
            @ErrSeverity int
    SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),@ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
END CATCH
```

Comment: What are you **table structures** (columns, datatypes)? And which indices do you have on those tables? How many rows of data are in those tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say exactly without knowing more about your database schema.  A few initial ideas might be to cleanup the *_DESC variables right away rather than doing the LTRIM and RTRIM in the WHERE clause.  Maybe consider or add to an index on the PACK table that includes COUNTRY_CD/COMPANY_CD (NOT description though, assuming it's long string text.  I would think COMPANY and COUNTRY are pretty small tables, but hopefully you have the proper indexes on those fields.  Might also be worth trying to join to those tables in DELETE rather than doing lookups ahead of time.

```
-- clenaup variables
-- these should be new vars, not input parms
SELECT @COUNTRY_DESC = LTRIM(RTRIM(@COUNTRY_DESC))
    ,@COMPANY_DESC = LTRIM(RTRIM(@COMPANY_DESC))
    ,PACK_DESC = LTRIM(RTRIM(@PACK_DESC ))

-- delete   
DELETE PACK
FROM PACK
JOIN COUNTRY ON PACK.COUNTRY_CD = COUNTRY.COUNTRY_CD
JOIN COMPANY ON PACK.COMPANY_CD = COMPANY.COMPANY_CD
WHERE   COUNTRY.COUNTRY_DESC = @COUNTRY_DESC 
AND COMPANY.COMPANY_DESC = @COMPANY_DESC
AND PACK.PACK_DESC = @PACK_DESC
```

Comment: hi,thanks for reply..tried your suggestion but it also taking same time execute

Answer (score 1):

> Try to evaluate the values of the variables @COUNTRY_CD and
>   @COMPANNY_CD in a separate proc and pass them as i/p parameter to this
>   proc and see if it helps. I have seen this issue in the past and the
>   solution that I just mentioned solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking within your stored procedure and check the Estimated Executon Plan. You can see how "expensive" your SP will be.

If need be you could try

https://stackoverflow.com/a/797968/1504882

Answer (score 0):

Make sure COMPANY is indexed on company_cd, COUNTRY on country_cd and PACK on company_cd,country_cd,pack_desc.

Delete from a large table would take some time without the right index.

Comment: hi, i have created index on PACK table like this              `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_pack_company_country_pack_desc] ON [dbo].[PACK]
(
 [PACK_CD] ASC
)
INCLUDE (  [COMPANY_CD],
 [PACK_DESC],
 [COUNTRY_CD]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO` is it right? and as company_cd and country_cd are primary keys i think they are already indexed..