# Stored procedure - return results without executing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd like to write a stored procedure for MS SQL Server 2008 that removes rows from a table... but if a certain argument is supplied, it would show what would be removed if it were ran normally at that moment, instead of actually removing.

For returning what would be removed, I could of course copy everything to be removed into a temp table and return the table.

But is there a built-in function that would allow that functionality?

I know execution plans can be helpful for debugging, but I don't see anything in the docs that come close to doing this (see esp [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/execute-a-stored-procedure) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-the-estimated-execution-plan), also SO question and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794411/how-can-i-display-the-execution-plan-for-a-stored-procedure))

Comment: So you want a procedure that will either return the results of a select query or perform a delete? This is a bit strange but not a huge deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow the T-SQL given below, where I am using a sample table `TABLE1` from which records need to be deleted.

The clause `OUTPUT Deleted.*` is a standard SQL Server feature that will automatically return all rows being deleted.

**Automatically show all rows being deleted**

```
--boolean parameter that tells whether to just show rows being deleted
--OR to actually delete the rows
DECLARE @delete BIT = 0;

BEGIN TRAN

DELETE FROM TABLE1
OUTPUT DELETED.*;

IF @delete = 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    COMMIT TRAN
END
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create three procedures for this. One is the "driver" procedure which decides which procedure to execute. This is important because execution plans can be a real problem when there are multiple execution paths. You can read more in depth about the performance implications here. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Something like this should work for you.

```
create procedure MyProc
(
    @DeleteData bit
) as

    if @DeleteData = 1
        exec MyDeleteProc
    else
        exec MySelectProc
```