# Table with 0 rows takes 14 seconds to join

Tags: sql-server, performance

Let me start off by saying I'm not a DBA.
I've had a report of a slow stored procedure in production.
Which I can't reproduce in testing.

Taking the stored procedure in question and examining the query, when two tables are joined and there is no data in one table, the join takes 12 seconds.
It seems to me that taking 12 seconds to return 0 rows is rather too long.
In testing it takes 0 seconds, as I would expect.

I can see on a second production environment running the same version of the code, an index scan is used instead of a table scan, and the results from the SP are sub-second as expected.

From that my conclusion is it's related to just one specific production server.

Depending on workload, a test query can take from 14s (all other machines idle) to 3min (three other machines working) on the production DB from SSMS.

I can't shake the feeling something is fundamentally upset here, and I've missed something obvious.

DBCC found no errors (as expected).

The table in question was once larger, and is now empty.
According to Table Properties|Storage
Data space 33,08.875MB
Index space 1.375MB
Row count 0

That sizing seems perfectly normal for a table where all the rows are deleted, as space isn't reclaimed during a delete, only truncate.

One possible clue is the large number of logical reads when joining a table with 0 rows to a table with 7 rows.

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'REDACTED'. Scan count 1, logical reads 432536 , physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Time:
CPU time = 12750ms, elapsed time = 12830ms.

High CPU time is expected on a table scan, I know that.

Why would a table scan of 0 rows take 432536 logical reads?

DBCC results for 'REDACTED'.
There are 0 rows in 423536 pages for object "REDACTED".

Which means in a table scan it has read each page when there are 0 rows.  Surely that's not right?

We have split out the troublesome join in the SP and are testing it in a new query of just joining two tables.  So recompiling the SP doesn't feel like a solution as we can reproduce the issue outside the SP.

On my test system, the table scan is very different:
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0
Table 'REDACTED'. Scan count 1, logical reads 0

Which is what I expected.
But then my storage is also data 0, index 0 because my table has never been populated.

Comment: Are you joining just plain flat tables, or subqueries? Is it a clustered table?

Comment: A good place to start is by providing an execution plan, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/797968/507793 on how to do so.  Also, if the data behind the scenes has changed drastically, it may be worthwhile to rebuild the execution plan, with `EXEC sp_recompile 'STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME_HERE'`

Comment: And turn on Query Store: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: David - Yes, I turned on Query Store this morning.
Indexes rebuilt, Statistics updated.

The Impaler - it's joining tables, not subqueries. 
There are two non-unique, non-clustered indexes.
No primary key (so help me Codd).

Comment: We can't tell you anything without tables and index definitions, the full query, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Performance issues are not usually a one-size-fits-all answer

Answer (score 1):

"table scan" means that the table is a heap and you also confirm this in the comments (just two **non clustered** indexes).

This is a normal problem for a heap. Empty pages generally don't get deallocated after a `DELETE`

```
USE tempdb

/*One row per page*/
SELECT TOP (1000) cast('X' as CHAR(5000)) AS X
INTO MyHeap
FROM sys.all_objects o1, sys.all_objects o2

DELETE FROM MyHeap

SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SELECT * FROM MyHeap /*logical reads 1000*/
```

You are being too relaxed about `Data space 3,308.875MB` and should [`TRUNCATE` or `REBUILD`](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sqlskills-sql101-why-does-my-heap-have-a-bunch-of-empty-pages/) the table so that the empty pages are deallocated and don't have to be scanned just to find out that they are empty.

> Why would a table scan of 0 rows take 432536 logical reads?

Because you need to deallocate these pages from the table.

Each page is 8KB. So there are 128 per MB. `128 * 3308.875` = `423536` - so this is the exact number you are asking about.

Comment: So all that remains is to confirm that this deletion of the rows is valid in the context of the use of the application on the project and there isn't a bug.
<br>
Then ALTER TABLE ... REBUILD.
<br>
I'd come to pretty much the same conclusion once I checked the DBCC results.
Thanks for confirming that I had worked it out correctly, Martin.